# Script Checkbox is not showing up and creating problem in my code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My Player_Collision script doesn't have a checkbox beside its name in Unity and it's creating a problem in my code now.
I coded to get an invincibility power-up for my Player but it doesn't seem to work for some reason now.
Power us is to make player invincible for short duration of time
I have attached my PowerUp and Player_Collision scripts as well.
How do I get the checkbox on my script back?

Also is it possible to disable OnCollisionEnter method for short period of time ?

[Unity Player_Collision screenshot of checkbox not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts3lv.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Invinciblity_PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer MeshR;



    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Pickup(other);

            
        }

    }

    void Pickup(Collider player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Power Up");
        player.GetComponent<Player_collision>().enabled = false;



        MeshR.enabled = false;
    }



}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player_movement pm;
    public Player_jump pj;



    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle" || collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Doorset")
        {
            pm.enabled = false;
            pj.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();




        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Player_collision is the current script, others have that little square because you can search for object to populate. To disable the collision methods, disable the Collider component.

Answer (score 0):

Only components with `Update`, `LateUpdate`, `FixedUpdate` and other "continuous" messages have the checkbox to indicate that they are currently `enabled`.

`OnTriggerEnter` doesnt care about the current `enabled` state.

You can simply check it yourself though by inside of whatever happens inside `Player_collision`

```
if(!enabled) return;
```

or alternatively as metnioned in the comments dis/enable the `Collider` rather then the `Player_collision`